# Different printout length for address

Tags: c

I have the following two print out. It's running on the same machine, I don't know why the length of address print out are different here.

Printout command:

```
   fprintf(stderr, "Prepare, size: %d, offset: %d, addr: %p\n", buf_sz, offset, buf);
```

Output:

```
Prepare, size: 16384, offset: 5799936, addr: 0x614000
```

The other printout command:

```
fprintf(stderr, "offset: %d, size: %d, base: %p\n", l_offset[i], size, base);
```

Output:

```
offset: 5799936, size: 16384, base: 0x2b2b95fc6000
```

I have one question about the print out for buf and base here. Why the length is different for those two? I thought they should have the same length, but different values to represent address.

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You have a 64-bit processor, so addresses are 16 hex characters long, but `%p` doesn't display the leading zeros. The first address is just much smaller than the second address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few guarantees for how a pointer is printed with `%p`, the standard just mandates "some implementation-defined manner":

> #### 7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function
>
> `p` The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>   manner.

Thus, the implementation must document how it prints, but is free to choose any suitable format, like "hexadecimal without leading zeroes, including prefix `0x`" (that is a variant of `%#X` with suitable length and converted argument).

If that representation has a different number of significant (not leading-zero) digits for two pointers, you get output of different length.

Answer (score 0):

Were these done in the same run of the same program?  Were the programs compiled differently?  Optimized differently?  I used to program using Borland C on DOS which would compile and link for different memory models, all of which could run on the same machine.

Lots of different things can happen during compiling, linking, and running.  Compiling is going to reduce your code to machine language that is understood by the processor.  These may have near and far pointers, depending on whether or not the target of the pointer is on the same memory page or not.  Was one variable declared locally, in which case it may have been allocated on the runtime stack, and the other globally, which may have been allocated on the heap?

I would try to read too much into the actual pointer values.